Getting error page.tsx:38 Error creating Manifest: TypeError: _libs_axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.post is not a function using axios
This is my 1st time using nextjs and I'm getting error page.tsx:38 Error creating Manifest: TypeError: _libs_axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.post is not a function when using Axios.
export default function useCreateManifestOutWard() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const createManifestOutWard = (data: ManifestRequestType) =>
        new Promise<string>(async (resolve, reject) => {

            let formData = new FormData();

            try {
                const response = await axiosInstance.post(apiUrl.manifest.create, {
                    ...formData,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                    isActive: true,
                });
            } catch (error) {
            }
        });
}

I was trying by change the promise thing but the error still popup

What's axiosInstance
